# Firebase Query Return Null

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Hello I am trying to query data in my firebase database by a category field which is under a specific node

Below is a snippet of my database to make what I just said a little easier to understand

```
 "events" : {
    "CCDS" : {
      "attend:count" : 2,
      "event:category" : "Seize The Day",
      "event:city" : "San Francisco",
      "event:date" : {
        "end:date" : "08/09/2017",
        "end:time" : "7:00 PM",
        "start:date" : "08/09/2017",
        "start:time" : "5:00 PM"
      },
      "event:description" : "Happy hour is more joyful in the summer thanks to Center City District Sips, which offers discounted drinks and appetizers every Wednesday evening.  Catch up with old friends and make a few new ones as Center City’s best bars and restaurants host the summer’s happiest hour every Wednesday from 5-7 p.m.  Enjoy $5 cocktails, $4 wine, $3 beers and half-price appetizers at dozens and dozens of bars and restaurants.",
      "event:imageURL" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/eventful-3d558.appspot.com/o/event_flyers%2FCCDS-compressor.jpg?alt=media&token=bcce3968-1cca-4890-a3d0-d8064bd0d1da",
      "event:name" : "center city district sips",
      "event:promo" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/eventful-3d558.appspot.com/o/event_promo_vid%2FMIA%2FBudweiser%20Made%20In%20America%20Festival%202013%20August%2031%20-%20September%201.mp4?alt=media&token=9b4b9d4f-2d6d-4762-a5fd-c72edb943ac4",
      "event:state" : "PA",
      "event:street:address" : "660 Chestnut St",
      "event:zip" : 19130
    },
    "DD" : {
      "attend:count" : 2,
      "event:category" : "I Love College",
      "event:city" : "New York",
      "event:date" : {
        "end:date" : "08/26/2017",
        "end:time" : "5:00 PM",
        "start:date" : "08/26/2017",
        "start:time" : "1:00 PM"
      },
      "event:description" : "Help us celebrate the hard work and creativity of the students and demo the iOS apps and games they've built in only 8 weeks! Developers, entrepreneurs, friends, and industry professionals are all welcome to attend",
      "event:imageURL" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/eventful-3d558.appspot.com/o/event_flyers%2Fmakeschooldemo-compressor.jpg?alt=media&token=1e75d18d-1949-48e8-a208-2ca88cde395b",
      "event:name" : "demo day",
      "event:promo" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/eventful-3d558.appspot.com/o/event_promo_vid%2FDD%2FDemo%20Night%202017%20-%20Make%20School%20Product%20College.mp4?alt=media&token=d9adb4b1-5689-4b15-96b2-e18138701526",
      "event:state" : "PA",
      "event:street:address" : "394 Broadway",
      "event:zip" : 10013
    },
    "MIA" : {
      "attend:count" : 23,
      "event:category" : "Seize The Night",
      "event:city" : "San Francisco",
      "event:date" : {
        "end:date" : "09/03/2017",
        "end:time" : "7:00 PM",
        "start:date" : "09/02/2017",
        "start:time" : "12:00 PM"
      },
      "event:description" : "Budweiser Made in America Festival is an annual music festival held in Philadelphia and formerly simultaneously held in Los Angeles.Sponsored by Anheuser–Busch and produced by Live Nation, the event features several stages that continuously host live music from a wide range of genres including hip hop, rock, pop, R&B, and EDM.",
      "event:imageURL" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/eventful-3d558.appspot.com/o/event_flyers%2FMadeInAmerica-compressor.jpg?alt=media&token=1ac6e794-6a1f-4f8a-bdb0-afc91f8ba6ae",
      "event:name" : "made in america",
      "event:promo" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/eventful-3d558.appspot.com/o/event_promo_vid%2FMIA%2FBudweiser%20Made%20In%20America%20Festival%202013%20August%2031%20-%20September%201.mp4?alt=media&token=11e5059f-3973-4a74-9c9b-a537b737e0ab",
      "event:state" : "PA",
      "event:street:address" : "Ben Franklin Parkway",
      "event:zip" : 19130
    },
    "MIA2" : {
      "attend:count" : 2,
      "event:category" : "Dress To Impress",
      "event:city" : "Philadelphia",
      "event:date" : {
        "end:date" : "09/03/2017",
        "end:time" : "7:00 PM",
        "start:date" : "09/02/2017",
        "start:time" : "12:00 PM"
      },
      "event:description" : "Budweiser Made in America Festival is an annual music festival held in Philadelphia and formerly simultaneously held in Los Angeles. Sponsored by Anheuser–Busch and produced by Live Nation, the event features several stages that continuously host live music from a wide range of genres including hip hop, rock, pop, R&B, and EDM. This is different regardless of the same name in database",
      "event:imageURL" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/eventful-3d558.appspot.com/o/event_flyers%2Fmadeinamerica2.jpg?alt=media&token=bd5eb5e4-4e22-4412-a34b-2dc6c9ae561e",
      "event:name" : "made in america",
      "event:promo" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/eventful-3d558.appspot.com/o/event_promo_vid%2FMIA%2FBudweiser%20Made%20In%20America%20Festival%202013%20August%2031%20-%20September%201.mp4?alt=media&token=11e5059f-3973-4a74-9c9b-a537b737e0ab",
      "event:state" : "PA",
      "event:street:address" : "Ben Franklin Parkway",
      "event:zip" : 19130
    },
    "MIA3" : {
      "attend:count" : 8,
      "event:category" : "21 & Up",
      "event:city" : "Philadelphia",
      "event:date" : {
        "end:date" : "09/03/2017",
        "end:time" : "7:00 PM",
        "start:date" : "09/02/2017",
        "start:time" : "12:00 PM"
      },
      "event:description" : "Budweiser Made in America Festival is an annual music festival held in Philadelphia and formerly simultaneously held in Los Angeles. Sponsored by Anheuser–Busch and produced by Live Nation, the event features several stages that continuously host live music from a wide range of genres including hip hop, rock, pop, R&B, and EDM.",
      "event:imageURL" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/eventful-3d558.appspot.com/o/event_flyers%2Fmadeinamerica3-compressor.jpg?alt=media&token=9166e2fb-ac9d-46d5-b06f-60cffc337b15",
      "event:name" : "made in america",
      "event:promo" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/eventful-3d558.appspot.com/o/event_promo_vid%2FMIA%2FBudweiser%20Made%20In%20America%20Festival%202013%20August%2031%20-%20September%201.mp4?alt=media&token=11e5059f-3973-4a74-9c9b-a537b737e0ab",
      "event:state" : "PA",
      "event:street:address" : "Ben Franklin Parkway",
      "event:zip" : 19130
    }
  }
```

I also have another node which stores all the events by location which I will also include below to clear up confusion

```
eventsbylocation" : {
    "37%2e7,-122%2e4" : {
      "event0" : "MIA",
      "event1" : "CCDS",
      "event2" : "MIA2",
      "event3" : "MIA3",
      "event4" : "DD"
    },
    "40%2e7,-74%2e0" : {
      "event" : "DD"
    }
  }
```

I am pulling the keys from the eventsbylocation node and then returning all of the events if they select the home category or one or more of the events if they are in a different category lets say "Seize the day" if I select that category it should return all information regarding CCDS.

The way I have my code setup is that for each key in eventsByLocation it checks the category field in the events node based off that key. If it matches it should return the relevant info however it is not returning anything,

Below is the code for my method that handles this

```
import Foundation
import Firebase
import FirebaseAuth


struct EventService {

    static func show(forEventKey eventKey: String, eventCategory: String? = nil, completion: @escaping (Event?) -> Void) {
       // print(eventKey)
        let ref = Database.database().reference().child("events").child(eventKey)
       // print(eventKey)

            if eventCategory == "Home" || eventCategory == nil || eventCategory == ""{
                //pull everything
                ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, andPreviousSiblingKeyWith: { (snapshot,eventKey) in
                    print(snapshot.value ?? "")
                    guard let event = Event(snapshot: snapshot) else {
                        return completion(nil)
                    }
                    completion(event)
                })

            }else{
                //pull based off of category
                print(eventCategory)
                print("Begin Query By Event Category")
                var query = ref.queryOrdered(byChild: "event:category").queryEqual(toValue: eventCategory)
                query.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
                    print(snapshot)

                }, withCancel: { (err) in
                    print("Failed to fetch event data")
                })
            }


    }
}
```

Any insight on what I might have done wrong? Because it is returning absolutely nothing at this point I know it is due to my query but I just can not figure out what is wrong with it.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind none of that was necessary i already had the category when I pulled the event object from that point all I had to was a simple string check before returning